# C# concurrent access to top N rows in Mongo DB

Tags: c#, mongodb, concurrency

Where multiple threads/processes are accessing the same collection in MongoDb and taking the top N records from the collection that match certain criteria,
is the possible to somehow block competing processes from accessing the same batch, I suppose I'm looking for something like a FindAndModify many for Mongo DB.

**For example**

```
var builder = Builders<QueuedMessageMongo>.Filter;
var filter = builder.Eq(qm => qm.Published, false);
var items = dbCollection.Find(filter).Limit(50);
```

Multiple threads/process will access the same items/rows in MongoDb, so is it possible to somehow update many rows while retrieving them from MongoDb, or is there an alternative approach which I am just not seeing from the documentation.

Comment: why are there Multiple threads/process? It sounds like you should rethink the design...but without more context its hard to say. why are lots of writes happening at the same time?

Comment: For active-active scenarios we need to do this, I was hoping there would be some sort of locking mechanism in MongoDb that we could use without having to implement our own.

Comment: I will be very SHOCKED!!! if MongoDb did not have this... I suspect your problem is something else..!!! like trying to write to the same context in two separate threads(not allowed).

Comment: I think your going to be shocked @Seabizkit, I've been trawling around all morning trying to figure out the best way to do this, as I thought the very same as you, there must be something in there.

Comment: What framework and version are using to make the connections to MongoDb from within c#, Also please include some more code... like the update/writing to db code.

Comment: The connection is a standard ImongoDatabase from an IMongoClient using a MongoUrl. Code for updating is a standard dbCollection.Update. I can't see how posting this code will help and in my opinion will only confuse matters. If there is some documentation you know of then please feel free to point me at it and I will gladly read it.

Comment: Just ensure you are creating a new dbCollection(connection) on each thread. hard to say without seing code. I get that you know what your talking about but could be a design threading issue? hard without seeing code...

Comment: I think you may be confused a bit @Seabizkit about what I'm asking. Anyway collections are sharable across threads with the C# driver, and as stated it won't make a difference to the question. I've been around the block on this one so unless someone has another opinion I'll end up implementing my own locking mechanism.

Comment: I assume you have been on MongoDb site? They mention that locking is built-in and that has support for some advanced locking(u made me google).I haven't worked with MongoDb, but the amount of times I've seen ppl mess this up with other data layers is mind blowing.I have seen ppl get this wrong with EF and SQL just cozs they thought it was safe to share a context between threads or werent aware that you cant do this. But it sounds like you have looked into this. Gd Luck, sozs i wasn't able to help.

Comment: You assume correctly, I've been all over the docs.

Comment: How about implementing repository and if your application happened to be updating, fetch fresh batch of selected top rows and cache locally. Think about readerwriterlockslim.

Comment: Thanks @Saleem, I can't see how that would work across different processes/servers. I'd still need some sort of locking mechanism.

Comment: I was thinking more sort of implementation of middle layer. all process are accessing assembly implementing this feature. again, readerwriterlockslim is a way of synchronization (locking)

Comment: Thanks @Saleem, but I still can't see how I would do this using native Mongo capabilities without doing my own locking, to ensure multiple processes and servers don't access the same data. I'm aware of the capabilities of ReaderWriterLockSlim